# Why is HR delaying in giving me an offer?

Tags: job-search, salary, follow-up

I recently attended an interview with one company and cleared all the rounds. In the HR round, I was asking for a salary which I feel I am worth and which I felt the company can pay. The HR person told me that it's above their maximum limit and she has to consult with her senior manager to decide whether to give me an offer or not. She explicitly mentioned that she will give me a call and tell me whether they intend to carry forward with an offer or to reject me. I said that's fine. I have been waiting for her call for the past 2 days, but have not received the call. <strike>Why is she delaying? Will she give me call? Will she revise the salary to my expectation?</strike>

I am thinking to follow up with her on this. What is the best way to follow up for this?

Comment: any reasons for down voting?

Comment: You're asking a question no one but the HR person can answer without wild speculation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations or agreements that are company-specific and don't have universally applicable answers.

Comment: If you're outside their range they're going to evaluate other candidates to see if they can get what they want 'in their pay band'. If not, they may call you back.

Comment: "Why is she doing this?" isn't a question we can answer.  A question about how long such followup should take or how to approach her would work better.

Comment: thats correct.. i will edit my question..

Answer (score 2):

Breathe.  Relax.  Job offers and job rejections can take longer than you expect, and they are working on their time, not yours. Two days is nothing in their time.

No-one knows the future, so no-one can answer the obvious question you are asking.  You may or may not get the offer, you may get another counter offer.

But these things take time.  She has to talk to someone else.  That someone else may be busy.  Perhaps his mother just died and he's taking some time off.  Perhaps something else came up in the business that trumps any hiring decisions right now.  Perhaps they just lost a big source of funding.  Perhaps, perhaps, perhaps.

At this point, your best bet is to move on.  Work on other applications.  If they call, they call, and at that point you can find out the answers to some of your questions.  But your worrying won't make them move any faster and will just cause stress for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning:** this is going to be blunt.

From an HR standpoint:

Considering the fact that you are asking for a salary above the maximum limit I can think of these reasons to wait as long as possible to get back to you:

- Other candidates are willing to work for less
- I have no other candidates but I would rather make you wait while I find some candidate than cave to your demands
- I hope you call and cave-in for a lower salary
- You are ballsy enough to ask for a larger salary now, so you will probably ask for a considerable raise in a year and that is not what the company wants

---

You stated that:

> She explicitly mentioned that she will give me a call and tell me whether they intend to carry forward with an offer or to reject me.

^ Nowhere in there did she specify an expected call-back date so they are just going to leave you hanging as long as they can afford to.

Comment: They very well may be looking at other candidates so they can withdraw the offer. Nobody wants to hire the greedy. If you are above their current maximum budgeted, they will likely not increase it for you unless they have already had several others reject the offer for the same reason. But even then they will still have to find the money somewhere as it is clearly not in the budget and that takes time.